# Relationship between a linear difference equation and the hyperbolic functions

Tags: least-squares, linear-algebra, function

Considering a linear difference equation
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
-p & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 1 &-p & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 0 & 1 &-p & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & -p & 1 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -p 
\end{bmatrix}}_P \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ x_{N-2} \\ x_{N-1} 
\end{bmatrix}}_x = -\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}}_C,
\end{equation}
where $p:=2+\tilde{\kappa}^2 \tau^2$ and $\tau:=T/N$ are given; sequence $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^{N-1}$ needs to be estimated by solving the linear difference equation.

Normally, the solution of a well-defined linear difference equation can be estimated using linear least squares (LLS), such that $x=-P^{-1}C$; however, according to the paper "Optimal Execution of Portfolio Transactions":

"a linear difference equation whose solution may be written as a combination of the exponentials $e^{\pm \kappa(j\tau)}$, where $\kappa$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{\tau^2}(\cosh(\kappa\tau)-1) = \tilde{\kappa}^2
\end{equation}
and the solution can be written as
\begin{equation}
x_j = \frac{\sinh(\kappa(T-j\tau))}{\sinh(\kappa T)} x_0.
\end{equation}"

Can anyone explain to me how $P^{-1}$ is related to the hyperbolic function $\sinh$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited for math SE but to old to migrate